# When should I create a separate controller instead of a custom action in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controllers

Consider an example where I have an `Orders` model.  Triggering the `index` action shows all of the orders in the system.

Now I want to have a separate page that displays a **chart** of all refunded orders and another page that displays all cancelled orders--not only is there now a filter, but a whole new view as well.

What would be a best practice:

1.) Creating new actions in `OrdersController` for each report (e.g., `refund_report` and `cancelled_report`)

2.) Creating new controllers for each report (e.g., `RefundReportController`, `CancellationReportController`) with a single `show` action?

3.) Creating one new controller for all reports (e.g., `OrderReportsController`) and an action for each report (e.g., `refunds`, `cancellations`, etc.

Or is there another paradigm I'm missing altogether?

Comment: @givanse I don't believe that question addresses when to divide a controller into multiple controllers vs. adding more actions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go with #1: create actions within `OrdersController` for each report. This is simple, and it makes sense that a resource (an `Order`) would have multiple views into it through its associated controller. You're not asking for anything specific to one of these reports yet and it's a good/simple pattern that 1 :get action (and route) corresponds to 1 view.

If, in the future, you find that you're doing a few things specific to a report then consider giving that report its own controller. But that may never happen and no need to abstract early and weigh yourself down now.

Basically, create a new Controller when you want to start thinking of that something as its own entity with its own actions. Don't break something out into a new controller just because the default REST options don't provide a specific member action for what you need.

Answer (score 3):

> *1.) Creating new actions in OrdersController for each report (e.g., refund_report and cancelled_report)*

This is a simple and straight-forward approach. Go with this, if all you are going to do is filter out `refunded orders` and `cancelled orders` from `Order` and display them on their independent views. Also, you don't wish to clutter the `index` action as well as `index` view. This is also a better approach if you are not planning on adding any more reports in future and clutter the `OrdersController`.

> *2.) Creating new controllers for each report (e.g., RefundReportController, CancellationReportController) with a single
>   show action?*

As per the details given in question, the view for `Refunded Orders` and `Cancelled Orders` is going to be primarily based on `Order` model. So, adding new controllers for each report doesn't seem feasible. What are these controllers going to do anyway, just have a single action for `refunds` or `cancellations` each? I would not recommend going with this approach.

> *3.) Creating one new controller for all reports (e.g., OrderReportsController) and an action for each report (e.g., refunds,
>   cancellations, etc.*

This is a better approach than both Approach #1 and Approach #2, provided in near future you are planning to add more reports on `Order` model. With this approach you would be *separating the concerns* by keeping `OrdersController` just for the `CRUD` activities on your `Order` model and `OrderReportsController` for all the reports that can be generated on the data retrieved from `Order`.

I would suggest you to select either **Approach #1** or **Approach #3** based on your *use-case*.